# Deploying sap spartacus for different environments

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

we are developing an e-commerce site with sap spartacus. We will have 2 different environments to publish this site in commerce cloud: s1, p1.

On the angular side, I created my environment files;

- environment.ts
- environment.staging.ts
- environment.prod.ts

In spartacus-configuration.module, I get the baseUrl and prefix information from the environment file.

```
backend: {
        occ: {
          baseUrl: environment.occ.baseUrl,
          prefix: environment.occ.prefix,
          ...
```

Project is located in js-storefront/spartacusstore folder.
manifest.json file is under the js-storefront directory and its content is as follows;

```
{
    "applications": [
        {
            "name": "spartacusstore",
            "path": "spartacusstore",
            "enableSSR": false
        }
    ],
    "nodeVersion": "16"
}
```

but when deploying in the cloud;

- ng build --configuration dev when deploying to d1
- ng build --configuration staging when deploying to s1
- ng build --configuration prod when deploying to p1
  I can't find how to define commands to work.

I found the following content in the document: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/b2f400d4c0414461a4bb7e115dccd779/1c26045800fa4f85a9d49e5a614e5c22.html

but I have no idea where to set it here.

Has anyone encountered this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

SAP hasn't provided any graceful way to allow configurations per environment via the environment.ts files. Raise a SAP ticket and they will help setup the api endpoint per environment but that might not be the case for any external api endpoints like  for payment etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).